# What is this permission group?

Tags: adb, permissions

When I ran `adb shell pm list permission-groups` one of the groups was: **com.google.android.gms.permission.CAR_INFORMATION**.

I've never seen this before in system settings and I can't find anything explaining what it is for.

Why does Google have a permission relating explicitly to cars?

Comment: Ever hear of Android Auto? Check the manifest, this permissions group has been around since Nougat, it includes getting information like fuel level, mileage, vehicle speed, etc. Many apps besides Android Auto itself are AA compliant, not an unusual permission at all for apps like media players, navigation software, messaging apps, etc.

Comment: Ya, I know about Android Auto, but I don't know why it's part of google play services and why this is the only such special case.

Comment: @Deoxal it's a part of Play Services because it's not a part of Android (AOSP). Google is providing this proprietary service as a third party app developer. Any app can define its own permissions.